# Is this internal engine component cracked?

Tags: engine, leak, pulsar, cracking

I was inspecting my engine (1.6L N15 Pulsar) yesterday and I noticed some moisture on the rocker cover coming from the oil fill cap. I unscrewed it and it looked like it was allowing some fluid out. I'm thinking the cap might need replacing.

I then had a look inside the oil fill and noticed what I think might be a crack in what I think might be part of the valve assembly?

My question is whether you guys believe that's a crack, what component has the crack and how I should go about it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit**
Something I forgot to mention is that the oil on the dipstick did have a few tiny bubbles in it which I haven't noticed before

Comment: It does look like a crack.  Are you having a problem?

Comment: @jwh20  Not necessarily, only issues I know of at the moment is an oil leak from the distributor. I've also been meaning to make a question about this but a couple times recently the car has had trouble turning on. It would turn on but quickly it would lose rpm and stall within a few seconds. I have to rev the engine for a few moments to get the engine going fine.

Comment: @jwh20 I also wanted to know how I can go about figuring out what components cracked and what issues this may cause

Comment: @jwh20 Somehting I forgot to mention is that the oil on the dipstick did have a few tiny bubbles in it which I haven't noticed before

Comment: That would not concern me as much as oil in the coolant or coolant in the oil.  It's not clear that this is a crack and even if it is, that it's a problem.  Unless you are having a problem I'd just leave it.  The alternative is to start opening things up to do a closer inspection.

Comment: @jwh20 Thanks for the advice I appreciate the effort. I'll keep an eye on things

Comment: I don't think that's a crack, Looks like a cast part. I think it's an uneven surface from the casting process

Answer (score 0):

That is the head; a part that holds a lifter. It  is likely caused by a crack in the sand core and the molten metal conformed to it. It would likely cost most of the price of an engine to replace it if it bothers you. Best guess from the available view.

Comment: As an old car guy who did everything himself , I  feel the urge to look for problems. The newer cars ( for roughly 30 years )  are so  trouble free it is difficult not to look for trouble. My 2011 Murano  has never needed service in 85,000 miles , so I change the oil myself  to do something. And wiper blades . It looks like brake pads will easily go over 100, 000 miles.